# jQuery ui tab の タブ画面内にて、リンクの展開？をおこないたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

お世話になっております。

現在、jQuery ui tab を用いた画面を作成しているのですが、タブ画面内にて、リンク先ページの読込方法がわかりません。

動きとしては、[タブAクリック]⇒[タブAにtest1.htmlが読込まれる]⇒[test1.htmlに記述されている、a href="test2.html" をクリック]⇒[タブAにtest2.html] が読込まれる･･･としたいと思ってます。
test1.htmlの読込みまでは問題ないのですが、その先がダメです。。。

フレーム等であれば、`<a href="xxx.html" target="_self">`のような記述で同じフレーム内にリンク先を読込みできますが、jQuery tabの場合に、同タブ内にリンク先を読込みをおこなうには、どのような方法をとればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

> 同タブ内にリンク先を読込みをおこなうには、どのような方法をとればよろしいでしょうか？

.load()関数を使用します。

$("#tabA").load("test2.html");
http://api.jquery.com/load/